# Classy lens in game programming for state management (mtl style)

Tags: haskell

In my game, I use a global `GameState`, which contains a list of `PlayerState`. The number of players is dynamic.

```
data PlayerState = PlayerState {
  _playerState_Id   :: Int,
  _playerState_Cash :: Int
                               }
data GameState = GameState {
  _gameState_CurrentPlayer :: Int,
  _gameState_PlayerStates  :: [PlayerState]
                           }

makeClassy ''PlayerState
makeClassy ''GameState

instance HasPlayerState GameState where
  playerState_Id = gameState_PlayerStates . ix 0 . Id
  playerState_cash = gameState_PlayerStates . ix 0 . cash
```

My goal is to update those fields in a `StateT` monad, with a function that looks like this:

```
update :: (MonadIO m,
           MonadState s m,
           HasPlayerState s,
           HasGameState s) => m ()
```

The problem is in the instance definition of `HasPlayerState`. I can only select a single element in the list. How to manage this nested state with list elements?

**Edit:**
I realize that I could use the Currentplayer field as an index. But now I seem to have a problem with `ix`

```
data PlayerState = PlayerState {
  _playerState_Cash :: Int
                               }
data GameState = GameState {
  _gameState_CurrentPlayer :: Int,
  _gameState_PlayerStates  :: [PlayerState]
                           }

makeClassy ''PlayerState
makeClassy ''GameState

instance HasPlayerState GameState where
  playerState = gameState_PlayerStates
  playerState_Cash = playerState . ix gameState_CurrentPlayer . playerState_Cash
```

With error:

```
 • Could not deduce (Applicative f) arising from a use of ‘ix’
      from the context: Functor f
        bound by the type signature for:
                   playerState :: Lens' GameState PlayerState
```

Comment: Hint: `gameState_CurrentPlayer` is a `Lens' GameState Int`, but `ix`'s argument should be an `Int`

Comment: Oh, and `ix` returns a `Traversal` but `playerState_Cash` should be a `Lens`.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson so how should I compose a Traversal and Lens?

Comment: You can compose a `Traversal` and a `Lens`, but the result is just a `Traversal`.